# I Need some javascript assistance

Tags: javascript

I recently made a post about this, but I phrased my question(s) wrong and stuff and deleted it so I go again.

Ok so I have a website for a schoolproject, it's pretty hasty because we're gonna deliver soon and we're just adding some visual stuff to make the site look nicer and more appealing, so yes, its for homework/project. So therefore I went and copied a clock-code somewhere which i managed to get working and i dont fully understand every bit of it. 
Here is the code:

```
tday  =new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
    tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

    function GetClock(){
    d = new Date();
    nday   = d.getDay();
    nmonth = d.getMonth();
    ndate  = d.getDate();
    nyear = d.getYear();
    nhour  = d.getHours();
    nmin   = d.getMinutes();
    nsec   = d.getSeconds();

    if(nyear<1000) nyear=nyear+1900;

         if(nhour ==  0) {ap = " AM";nhour = 12;} 
    else if(nhour <= 11) {ap = " AM";} 
    else if(nhour == 12) {ap = " PM";} 
    else if(nhour >= 13) {ap = " PM";nhour -= 12;}

    if(nmin <= 9) {nmin = "0" +nmin;}
    if(nsec <= 9) {nsec = "0" +nsec;}


    document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
    setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);
    }
    window.onload=GetClock;

<h:body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">
<h5 id="clockbox">x</h5>
```

Ok, since my experience with javascript is pretty dire, I dont understand the IF-sentences, like what does 1000 and 1900 mean in this sort of scenario? where does AP come from? in the nmin and nsec, i understand what happens but can't explain... also the clockbox, what is innerHTML in this case?

I hope this post and explanation is better..

Comment: They mean 1000 and 1900. They're numbers. ap is a variable.

Comment: You should consider using a proper indentation, these one-liners are not improving readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )` means call every 1000 ms the `updateClock()` method.

The following code converts 24 hour notation to 12 hour notation.

```
if(nhour ==  0) { // if the current time is 00:xx
  ap = " AM";
  nhour = 12;
} else if(nhour <= 11) { // if it's before 12
  ap = " AM";
} else if(nhour == 12) { // if the current time is 12:xx
  ap = " PM";
} else if(nhour >= 13) { // if it's passed 12
  ap = " PM";
  nhour -= 12;
}
```

To add leading zeros, the following code:

```
if(nmin <= 9) {
  nmin = "0" + nmin;
}
if(nsec <= 9) {
  nsec = "0" + nsec;
}
```

Note that with these assignments the type changes.

To actually display the clock on the website:

```
document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML= "something";
```

But for this code there needs to be an element in the HTML with `id='clockbox'` therefore the following HTML code is placed somewhere on the page:

```
<h5 id="clockbox">x</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all variables, so use:

```
var d = new Date();
var nday   = d.getDay();
var nmonth = d.getMonth();
...
```

and so on.

> I dont understand the IF-sentences

The following:

```
if (nhour ==  0) {
  ap = " AM";
  nhour = 12;

} else if (nhour <= 11) {
  ap = " AM";

} else if (nhour == 12) {
  ap = " PM";

} else if (nhour >= 13) {
  ap = " PM";
  nhour -= 12;
}
```

converts 24 hour time into 12 hour time with am/pm. It can be replaced by:

```
var ap = nhour < 12? ' AM' : ' PM';
nhour  = nhour % 12 || 12;
```

.

> like what does 1000 and 1900 mean in this sort of scenario

The *getYear* function returns a two digit year for years in the 20th century (1900 to 1999). You can avoid that by using *getFullYear*, which returns all the digits for the year:

```
var nyear = d.getFullYear();
```

and remove the `if(nyear<1000) nyear=nyear+1900;` statement.

> where does AP come from?

I think you mean *ap*. It's an undeclared variable, it should be declared with `var` (as should all the variables in the function).